# Nova not supporting while using with keystone v3

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, keystone

i am using keystone v3 in my devstack setup and i am trying to delete an nova instance, :

```
        from keystoneclient.v3 import client as keyclientv3
        from novaclient import client as nova_client
        from keystoneauth1 import session

        keystone= keyclientv3.Client(username="neutron",password="mysecret",
                        user_domain_name="default",
                        project_domain_name="default",
                        project_name="service",
                        auth_url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3/')

        token = keystone.auth_token

        sess = session.Session(auth=keystone, verify=False)

        nova = nova_client.Client(self.nova_version, auth_token=token,
                                  tenant_id=tenant_id,
                                  auth_url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3/',
                                  session=sess)
        nova.servers.delete(instance_id)
```

but i am getting error "The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)"

Comment: Are you sure that `instance_id` is the ID (not name) of a (still) existing instance?

Comment: yes,  its an ID of an existing instance.

Comment: Then the next steps should be to check the logs, increase the logging level, check the database .... and finally start debugging the server-side with a python debugger.